# How to load memory address without using pseudo-instructions?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

I'm trying to learn MIPS assembly language by myself using **MARS simulator**.

For didactic reasons I'm limiting myself to not using pseudo-instructions.

While trying to get the address of some data into a register, I ran into a problem because I cannot use `la`.

I tried using `lui` in combination with `ori`, the same as if I was to load a number directly, to no avail:

```
  .data
arr:
  .byte 0xa1
  .byte 0xb2
  .byte 0xc3
  .byte 0xd4
  .byte 0xe5
  .byte 0xf6
  .byte 0x7a
  .byte 0x8b
  .byte 0x9c
  .byte 0xad

.text

  lui $s0, mem # <--- mars just gives me errors here :(
  ori $s0, mem # ?? ...
```

Is this doable using *specifically MARS, without pseudo-instructions*? How?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the modified question "*is this doable using specifically MARS, without pseudo-instructions?*": From a quick scan of the MARS documentation, it appears not.  MARS appears to be intentionally restricted for pedagogical purposes.

If you want to try this on a full MIPS simulator that will simulate the Linux OS running on MIPS and run code built with the gnu toolchain, take a look at the [OVP Simulator](http://www.ovpworld.org/download_MIPS.php).  This is free and runs on Linux and Windows, but it's probably a *lot* more than you need.

Comment: You again! Thanks for the insight. :) Yeah I suspected it wasn't possible but just thought it was a major flaw for the designers to make pseudo-instructions do what you cannot achieve with actual instructions. I'll give OVP a try and wait a pair of days to see if someone comes up with a solution, if not the bounty is yours ;)

Comment: @Trinidad: I just tried it as well and you can't even do `li $t0, 2+2`, so I agree with markgz that it doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 3):

You need to refer to a label in the data section in the lui and ori instructions.  This works for gnu assembler (as):

```
    .data
lab1: .byte 0xa1
...
.text
    lui   $s0,      %hi(lab1)
    addiu $s0, $s0, %lo(lab1)
    lb    $s2, 0($s0)
...
```

The `%hi` and `%lo` directives tell the linker what is going on, so that it can put the address of the label "lab1" in the machine code.

Use `lui` ; `addiu` rather than `lui` ; `ori` with `%hi`/`%lo`: the expansion of `%hi` depends on `%lo` being treated as negative if its high bit is set.

This allows `lui $t0, %hi(sym)` ; `lb $t1, %lo(sym)($t0)` to work using the `%lo` as the immediate offset in the load, without a separate instruction to materialize the full address in a register.  Loads and stores treat their immediate as signed like `addiu`, unlike `ori`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ori` instructions needs still another operand to work and as far as I looked over your code, "mem" is no existing label.
Try this one:

```
.data 0x10000000 #or choose any other location
        #pointer section
        .word arr
        #...

        #pointed section
arr:    .byte #...  only as tip, you can separate multiple values with comma
              #behind .byte so that you don't need multiple .byte directives 
        #...

.text
        #...
        lui $s0, 0x1000
        lw $t0, 0($s0)           #get the value of "arr"
        #...
```

If it doesn't work, MARS likely won't be able to get label content without pseudo instructions.