# MIPS la keyword

Tags: mips, memory-address, spim

Let's say have a variable var stored at address 0x00001000 and the value of it is 10.

If i did
la $t2, var

Would $t2 contain the address of var or the value of var. I really want to say the address, considering la stands for load address, but everywhere I've looked the examples don't make that explicit connection.

Also I know this is broken down to
lui
ori 
in native instructions but how would it look exactly?

Answer (score 0):

`$t2` would contain the address var, not the content (to get the content, you need lw or something alike).

`la` is indeed a pseudoinstruction. For more information about how this is used, have a look at this question and answer:

[MIPS: The Equivalent of la instruction without using pseudo codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535228/mips-the-equivalent-of-la-instruction-without-using-pseudo-codes)