# MIPS getting around using pseudo-instructions, What is going wrong?

Tags: assembly, mips

My question is about how I'm supposed to get around the use of pseudo-instructions such as `la` and `li`. Many Internet sources just use pseudo-instructions anyway, which confuses me to some extent.
Part of my problem is with what is going wrong with this snippet. The simulator spits out a syntax error with the `liu` instruction and I don't understand what is going wrong.

From my understanding, the `liu` command grabs the significant bits, shifts left 16 bits, and puts that in the register ($a0). The `ori` instruction takes the label, and performs an OR on the lower 16 bits which is effectively adding it to the register.

```
       .data
m1:    .asciiz "Some string"

       .text
main:   
       lui     $a0, m1        # loads m1 into $a0 to be printed
       ori     $a0, $a0, m1
```

Am I not supposed to use the label m1 for `liu` or `ori`? And if I'm not meant to, what do I do instead?

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535228/mips-the-equivalent-of-la-instruction-without-using-pseudo-codes) and I understand what is supposed to be happening, but I'm still not sure as to why my instructions has a different effect, and why there is a `andi $a0,$a0,0x0000ffff` before the `liu` and `ori` commands.

The MIPS simulator I'm using is QtSpim if that is relevant.
I've gone looking for answers to this question here and elsewhere, and I've failed to understand them. 
Any help/corrections would be wonderful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in the referenced answer is unfortunately incorrect.
It should be:

```
lui $a0, m1 >> 16
ori $a0, $a0, m1 & 0xffff
```

The only problem with that is that SPIM doesn't seem to support these operators on labels.

Anyway, the logic is that you have to split the 32 bit address into 2 halves, and load them separately. Right shifting by 16 gives you the top 16 bits (the shift will be reversed by the `lui` at runtime) while masking with `0xffff` gives you the low 16 bits.

GNU assembler has special support functions `%hi` and `%lo` to get the high and low halves. With them you can write equivalent code as follows:

```
lui     $a0, %hi(m1)       # loads m1 into $a0 to be printed
ori     $a0, $a0, %lo(m1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! You've cleared up what was going wrong and explained the logic in a simple way!